# Forward plain-text emails to TLS enabled SMTP server?

Tags: ssl, email, smtp, email-server, smtp-auth

I am running old applications that are not supporting any encryption/authentication  protocol on outgoing e-mails.

Is it possible to send plain-text emails to a local "relay" server that forward it to a TLS enabled SMTP server?

Comment: This is entirely practical and configured "out the box" by most "general purpose" SMTP servers work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly possible. And it is not even a strange scenario.

In fact, SMTP is not an end to end connection between mail client and final server but the mail client usually submits the mail to some local SMTP server which then delivers the mail to the next server etc. And this can take multiple hops. The connection between these hops might be encrypted with TLS or might be not. There might be authentication between the hops but usually there is none.

In other words: this setup fits well into the architecture of SMTP. This means it is supported by many mail servers, among them Postfix.